# Credit Card Validation Check (Using Luhn's Algorithm)

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, checksum

```
list = int(input("Enter the first 15 digits of your credit card number without spaces and dashes: "))
checkDigit = int(input("Enter the last digit of the credit card number: "))
numbers = []
for elements in str(list):
    numbers.append(int(elements))

def main():
    n = None
    total_odd = 0
    total_even = 0
    count = 0
    for element in numbers[::2]:
        total_odd += element
        if element > 4:
            count += 1
    for element in numbers[1::2]:
        total_even += element
    total = total_even + (total_odd * 2) + count
    if total % 10 != 0:
        for i in range(1,10):
            if (total + i) % 10 == 0:
                n = i
    else:
        n = 0
    validation(n)

def validation(n):
    if n == checkDigit:
        print("Your credit card is valid!")
    else:
        print("Your credit card in not valid!")

main()
```

Comment: Please add a description of where this problem came from and a link if applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your program and functions are structured ineffectively**. You have some code
at the top level (collecting user input and converting it to `numbers`), then
most of the card-checking logic in `main()`, and a tiny bit of printing logic
in `validation()`. Much better would be a structure like the sketch below. In
`main()` we handle the user interactions (getting input and printing) and we
use a function like `validate_credit_card_number()` to handle the detailed
logic and return true or false. This structure is better for a variety of
reasons, one being that it makes it much easier to subject the validation
function (which is where the greatest potential for errors lies) to a battery
of automated tests. Note also that we end up with no logic at the top level (the sooner you embrace this habit, the better).

```
def main():
    ccnum = input(...)
    if validate_credit_card_number(ccnum):
        print('valid')
    else:
        print('invalid')

def validate_credit_card_number(ccnum):
    # Details shown below.
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Converting the card number to the needed lists of digits**. There are easier
ways to handle such tasks, mostly using indexing and slicing techniques that
you already appear to know about:

```
# Convert a big int to a list of its digits.
digits = [int(d) for d in str(ccnum)]

# Grab the last digit.
check_digit = digits[-1]

# Grab two groups of every-other digits, taken from the first 15 digits.
odds = digits[0:16:2]
evens = digits[1:16:2]
```

**Counting the number of odds greater than 4**. This can also be done
more simply via Python's `sum()` function and the fact that boolean
outcomes can be treated arithmetically.

```
n_big_odds = sum(o > 4 for o in odds)
```

**Simplifying the computation of the expected check digit**. Your approach
seems overly complex. Via experimentation with different inputs, I inferred the
following pattern. [Someone more fluent in the rules of modulo arithmetic than
I might be able to simplify it further.]

```
checksum = sum(evens) + (sum(odds) * 2) + n_big_odds
expected = (10 - (checksum % 10)) % 10
```

**The final check**. And then the function should just return a boolean
value.

```
return expected == check_digit
```